# Sound of ringing gels

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, gel

I'm searching for an audio file of the ringing of a ringing gel - does anyone know a source?

(I already searched on different video- and sound-platforms and looked up in the literature)

Answer (score 4):

From [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82230/the-mysterious-reverb-in-a-jar-of-hair-gel) question on Physics SE, there is a linked audio track in Soundcloud [here](https://soundcloud.com/wiebe-marten/gel-reverb-question-example), which is what you are looking for. The OP references a jar of hair-stying gel which, upon being tapped with a mallet, produces a "reverberating" sound instead an otherwise expected "short 'tok' sound."

Note the the ringing gels are common ingredients in pomades, shampoos, and other products where rheological properties are engineered for various reasons. See [this patent application for a ringing gel](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4026818A/en), wherein it is stated:

> The phenomenon of ringing is a result of the manner in which the dispersed droplets are entrapped within the network structure of a gel. It has been suggested that the network within a gel consists of a rod-like or lamellar structure. Such a network could allow dispersed particles to vibrate within a gel much like a ball bounces off the walls of a box.

The practical application of the gels appears to be mainly in the cosmetics industry.

Comment: Fascinating. I did not know this is a thing.